# Which versions of graphql-js and graphql-relay-js are required to support file upload via the Relay Mutation getFiles function?

Tags: file-upload, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I am currently trying to upload a file via Relay but I am receiving a syntax error from our GraphQL server implementation whenever I try to execute the mutation. I am currently using graphql-js-0.4.18 and graphql-relay-js-0.3.6. I am assuming that one (or both) of these package versions is the culprit. Does anyone know which minimum versions of these packages I would need to properly support file uploads? I am forced to port these packages to a different language which is why I am concerned about the minimum versions required. Thanks in advance!

**Mutation Request**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKwC5gIWABIRSXoeW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"

mutation UploadFileMutation($input_0:CTI_Mutation_UploadFileInput!) {
  uploadFile(input:$input_0) {
    clientMutationId,
    ...F0
  }
}
fragment F0 on CTI_Mutation_UploadFilePayload {
  success
}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKwC5gIWABIRSXoeW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="variables"

{"input_0":{"fileName":"test_file_upload.txt","clientMutationId":"3"}}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKwC5gIWABIRSXoeW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test_file_upload.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryKwC5gIWABIRSXoeW--
```

**Mutation Response**

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:2) Invalid number, expected digit but got: \"-\".\n\n1: ------WebKitFormBoundaryKwC5gIWABIRSXoeW\n    ^\n2: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"query\"\n","locations":[{"column":2,"line":1}]}]}
```

Comment: I reviewed the release notes for both packages and did not see anything that explicitly called out the file upload feature.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this was not a GraphQL / Relay issue at all. I simply had to add support to my WebServer for multipart/form=data processing and now I am able to successfully upload files.

Comment: how did you handle upload in graphql

Comment: In my mutation, I used the getFiles() function and passed in the file that was selected by the user via a file picker. Then, on my server, I added support for multipart/form-data processing. This will be server dependent functionality. In my case, I was using a custom web server based on Owin which was written in C#.